# How to save css style after hover action

Tags: jquery, css

During implementing Menu control using jquery and css I got the following issue:

[**Here is live demo I've created to show my current problem**](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/85V6P/)

When I hover, for example, on **'Menu Item 1'** this item has changed style (`background: white;`) and it's ok, but when I want to cross it's children (**Sub Menu Item 1**, **Sub Menu Item 2** etc.) **Menu Item 1** must keep `background: white;` but it doesn't work in my example.

Also, when hover on **Menu Item 2**, previous style of menu item (**Menu Item 1**) should be changed to default.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Here is the code from the fiddle in case of link-rot:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="jsddm">
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
</ul>​
```

**Script**

```
var timeout = 200;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function jsddm_open() {
    jsddm_canceltimer();
    jsddm_close();
    ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').eq(0).css('visibility', 'visible');
}

function jsddm_close() {
    if (ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
}

function jsddm_timer() {
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);
}

function jsddm_canceltimer() {
    if (closetimer) {
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open);
    $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout', jsddm_timer);
});

document.onclick = jsddm_close;​
```

**CSS**

```
/* menu styles */
#jsddm
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    background: #4370b6;
    width: 100%;
}

#jsddm > li
{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    font: 12px Tahoma, Arial;
    background: #4370b6;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

#jsddm > li a
{
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 62px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

#jsddm > li a:hover
{
    background: #FFF;
    color: #4370b6;
    padding: 0 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,17);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,17);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,17);
}

#jsddm li ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#jsddm li ul li
{
    float: none;
    display: inline;
    width: auto;
    background: #0b0b0b;
    color: #FFF;
}

#jsddm li ul li a
{
    height: 40px;
    min-width: 240px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,17);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,17);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,17);
    background: #FFF;
    color: #0b0b0b;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 40px; /* IR Fix */
}

#jsddm li ul li a:hover
{
    /*background: #4370B6;
    color: #FFF;*/
}​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your css. you have the following declared:

```
#jsddm > li a:hover
{
    background: #FFF;
    color: #4370b6;
    padding: 0 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,17);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,17);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,17);
}
```

Just change that to:

```
#jsddm > li:hover > a, #jsddm > li:hover > ul a:hover
{
    background: #FFF;
    color: #4370b6;
    padding: 0 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,17);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,17);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,17);
}
```

and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```css
#jsddm > li a:hover
```

to

```css
#jsddm > li:hover a
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/85V6P/1/)

Comment: When you do it this way, the submenu links loose the hover state and are at every time blue.

Comment: Thank you Zoltan for the quick reply, but as Sven said submenu links loose the hover state, so his answer is more acceptable for me.